# How to burn a Windows iso to a USB device with WoeUSB?

Tags: windows, woeusb

In Ubuntu how to burn a Windows .iso to a USB device with WoeUSB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Solved - How to burn a Windows .iso to a USB device?

```
sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso /dev/sdb
```

```
sagar@sagar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/Documents$ sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso /dev/sdb
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdb...
/dev/sdb: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (dos): 55 aa
/dev/sdb: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
Ensure that /dev/sdb is really wiped...
Creating new partition table on /dev/sdb...
Creating target partition...
Making system realize that partition table has changed...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
mkntfs completed successfully. Have a nice day.
--2018-12-16 08:28:04--  https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/raw/master/res/uefi/uefi-ntfs.img
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.112|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbatard/rufus/master/res/uefi/uefi-ntfs.img [following]
--2018-12-16 08:28:05--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbatard/rufus/master/res/uefi/uefi-ntfs.img
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 151.101.192.133, 151.101.128.133, 151.101.64.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.192.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 524288 (512K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/WoeUSB.BeXrvh.tempdir/uefi-ntfs.img’

uefi-ntfs.img       100%[===================>] 512.00K  3.19MB/s    in 0.2s    

2018-12-16 08:28:06 (3.19 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/WoeUSB.BeXrvh.tempdir/uefi-ntfs.img’ saved [524288/524288]

1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
524288 bytes (524 kB, 512 KiB) copied, 0.289953 s, 1.8 MB/s
Mounting target filesystem...
Applying workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
Copying files from source media...
Installing GRUB bootloader for legacy PC booting support...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing custom GRUB config for legacy PC booting...
Resetting workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1544929040_7202"...
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_target_1544929040_7202"...
You may now safely detach the target device
Done :)
The target device should be bootable now
sagar@sagar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/Documents$
```

It took around two hours, 120 minutes or so.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get `wipefs: error: /dev/sdb: probing initialisation failed: No medium found`.  With the USB stick mounted it's certainly mounting at `/dev/sdb1`, so I don't really get it.